# Unreal From Source

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am having issues building Unreal Engine From Source. I have gotten anywhere from RosanaceAudio Errors to the whole UE4 Solution saying not compatible with my VS 2017.

I am using the release version of Unreal on github and ran setup and generate bat files.

I would give the exact errors but I can not build it again since it says that its incompatible.

Thank you! If you need more details please let me know!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEqU3.png)

Comment: 2017 support has been dropped from 4.25 on. You could either get 2019 or an earlier version of unreal.

Answer (score 1):

You should download visual studio 2019 or use an older version of the engine.